# In Struts2 named variable not getting cleared when redirected to another action

Tags: redirect, struts2, named-parameters, valuestack

I am having a weird problem when redirecting to an action from another action. In short the named  variable captured in the first action (from which I am redirecting) is still preserved somehow in the value stack and it is overwriting the same named variable in the second action. I will explain via some code.

```xml
<action name="r/{seoURL}" class="ReportsAction"
    method="displayReport">
    ...
    <result name="REDIRECT_TO_NEXT_ACTION" type="redirectAction">
        <param name="actionName">s/${seoURLForRedirect}</param>
        <param name="namespace">/reports</param>
    </result>
    ...
</action>
```

I am setting the variable `${seoURLForRedirect}` in `ReportsAction` before returning.
I have the following mapping for the second action.

```xml
<action name="s/{seoURL}" class="ReportSeriesAction"
    method="displayReportSeries">
    ...
</action>
```

As you can see I have same named variable in my second action `seoURL`. This value is set to the value as found in the first action. I fail to understand why is the value stack still maintaining `seoURL` value set in  the first action. Especially since I am over writing it in my redirect result params.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your `class` action attribute, I'm assuming you're using the Spring plugin.

Actions must be declared as `scope="prototype"`/non-singleton to be instantiated per-request.

If they're not, you're using a singleton, and properties will be maintained across requests.

I've never tried to set a `redirectAction`'s `actionName` to a wildcard that points to another wildcarded action, so I'm not sure about the second part of the question.

Comment: Thanks Dave. I guess that explains the behavior I am seeing. I guess I will have to use some other variable. Which will be redundant code. Oh, Well.

Comment: @Chantz Not sure what you mean; the prototype/singleton part shouldn't affect anything important. Regarding the redirectAction, I'm not saying it doesn't/won't work, I'm just saying I've never tried that.

Comment: It is affecting the seoURL variable. This is present in both the first & second action. And it seems to overwrite this variable when I am immediately redirecting from the first action to the second one. Re: redirectAction, I changed my approach to use "redirect". So for now I am fine.

Comment: @Chantz ... Struts 2 is designed to use an instance-per-request; this should not be surprising behavior. If it's set as a wildcard or parameter it'll be set on the action.